# Silence FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish, omnifaces

So after being confronted with the dreaded `javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException`, I had to go look around the internet to find the proper solution.  Fortunately, the solutions are readily available and I went ahead and adopted the OmniFaces [FullAjaxExceptionHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler).

Enough said, as with pretty much everything from OmniFaces, it worked wonders.  But, every time I have a view expiring I am getting :

```
SEVERE: WebModule[/myModule]FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/WEB-INF/errorpages/test.xhtml' will be shown.
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/my/page.xhtml - View /my/page.xhtml could not be restored.
...
```

This is fine as it is handled as expected, but **is there anyway to silence this exception from being printed to the server.log**?  This would crowd the log pretty quickly.

I am running : 
Mojarra 2.1.23 
PrimeFaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT
OmniFaces 1.6-SNAPSHOT-2013-07-01

on
Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per OmniFaces 1.6, you can extend it and override the method [`logException()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/exceptionhandler/FullAjaxExceptionHandler.html#logException-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.Throwable-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) as below to skip the stack trace for `ViewExpiredException`.

```
public class YourAjaxExceptionHandler extends FullAjaxExceptionHandler {

    public YourAjaxExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    protected void logException(FacesContext context, Throwable exception, String location, String message, Object... parameters) {
        if (exception instanceof ViewExpiredException) {
            // With exception==null, no trace will be logged.
            super.logException(context, null, location, message, parameters);
        }
        else {
            super.logException(context, exception, location, message, parameters);
        }
    }

}
```

Create a factory around it:

```
public class YourAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory extends ExceptionHandlerFactory {

    private ExceptionHandlerFactory wrapped;

    public YourAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory(ExceptionHandlerFactory wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
        return new YourAjaxExceptionHandler(getWrapped().getExceptionHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandlerFactory getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

}
```

In order to get this to run, register it as factory in `faces-config.xml` the usual way (don't forget to remove the original registration for `FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory`):

```xml
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>com.example.YourExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

Comment: @BalusC a switch is missing in `MyAjaxExceptionHandler#logException`.  This line needs to be inside the else: `super.logException(context, exception, location, message, parameters);`.  Also, if I'm not mistaken the faces-config.xml `<exception-handler-factory>` needs to be com.example.MyAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory.